# Does python alter the parameters if not passed while executing a function?

Tags: python

for example:

```
#creating the function with params
    def symlinks(release_path, deploy_to, settings_file, roll_back=False, is_file=False):
        #doing something with all the params

#executing the function
symlinks(releasepath, deploypath, settingsfile, is_file=true)
```

So there are multiple ways of passing parameters to functions in python, is the above one valid?

i tried symlinks(releasepath,deploypath,True) but seems like it is impacting roll_back.
Would the roll_back param be still false?

Comment: since `roll_back` already has a default value, it does not need to be included in the function call unless you are changing its value

Comment: so currently, i am changing the values in two different ways, is that okay?

Comment: the only thing I see wrong with your *executing the function* section is that `is_file=true` should have `True` capitalized. But everything else looks fine.

Comment: I don't wish to be sarcastic, but: what happened when you tried? This is a very easy experiment. Jump in and see if what happens is what you expected. :-)

Comment: What is the actual question? Did you try something that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the coolest way for you to find the answer to your question, would be using [`inspect.getcallargs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs). You can learn a lot by playing with it.

```
import inspect
inspect.getcallargs(symlinks, 'releasepath', 'deploypath', 'settingsfile', is_file=True)
=>
{'deploy_to': 'deploypath',
 'is_file': True,
 'release_path': 'releasepath',
 'roll_back': False,
 'settings_file': 'settingsfile'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python will bind the passed in values to the positional parameter names in the order they are passed, unless you specify a parameter name explicitly.

In your case, if you invoked the function with: `symlinks(releasepath,deploypath,True)`, then the default values would be used for the remaining 2 parameters  (`roll_back` and `is_file`).

See documentation:  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments